# Xcode 11 : Display problem after updated Xcode 10 to Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am a novice in Swift. I have developed a small application with Xcode10. When I upgrade Xcode 10 to 11 version, all the views changed. Now, I see at the top of all views a small part of my first view (behind). When I scrolled down the view, I see my first view. It will more clear with the picture:

[image]

How can I do to avoid that?

Comment: This is happening because you are presenting view controllers. Nothing wrong with the  Xcode, it's due to iOS 13's new window approach. you can use following code to present full-screen presentation -
`viewControler.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

Comment: Thank you at first for your quick answer. Where I put this code?

Comment: Based on your description, I assume you mean that the window changes appear only iOS 13 - Xcode 11 uses iOS13  in the simulator. If you have iOS devices running iOS 12 or earlier, they wouldn't have this new behavior.

Comment: @YvonAv where depends if you are presenting it programmatically or using the storyboard https://www.appsdissected.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Screen-Shot-2019-08-28-at-11.03.59.png

Comment: Thank you for your help. It' OK. I use storyborad

Answer (score 1):

This is the new behavior on iOS 13, you can use the snippet to change it back to full screen.

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle

Comment: Thanks, but where I put this code ? In my first/maine swift ViewController or ?

Comment: Yes, so you have to add it where the current viewController is presented, if possible you can also share your code in you question.

Comment: import UIKit

class FittingViewController: UIViewController{
    // Declaration nom et icon TabBar
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)
        tabBarItem=UITabBarItem(title: "Fittings", image: UIImage(named: "fitting-icon"), tag: 2)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        AppDelegate.AppUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all)
    }
}

Comment: which ViewController is presenting FittingViewController?